# jQuery tooltip when hovering text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a custom tooltip which appears when a user hovers over text, and disappears when the cursor goes elsewhere. However, because of the spaces between text, the tooltip disappears and reappears in a very jittery fashion.

What behavior should I keep in mind to avoid this? It seems that the only way to have `hover()` activate on a block of text is to have it when the cursor goes over the actual character (and hides when it reaches a gap).

**EDIT**: Solved, `onmouseenter()` and `onmousemove()` were able to do the trick. Unfortunately this is just a drawback of `hover()`

Comment: Do you have a code sample you can show? What are the characters wrapped in, a div, span, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

Try wrapping the text in a span and attach the hover to the span instead.

Comment: might also be a good idea to add a class to the `span` in case not all text wrapped with a `span` have tooltips

Comment: wrapping it in a span didn't work unfortunately. I'll edit with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a delay on the hover event to make sure that someone *wants* to hover?

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: My suggestion doesn't seem to address the same problem that Walkerneo is addressing... I think I misunderstood what the problem was...